# How to add 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons along with "listbox" in DataTable pagination

Tags: html, datatables, pagination

I'm using server side Data Table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "sPaginationType": "listbox"
      } );
  } );
```

When i add `"pagingType": "simple"` it hides list box.

[image]

I wants to add both options in the datatable pagination.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own [pagination-plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/) based on the [official listbox-example](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/select) and extend that with the buttons and behaviour you need.

**Here is an quick example i put together for the current version (v1.10.19) of datatables:**

```js
$.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.listboxWithButtons = {
    "fnInit": function (oSettings, nPaging, fnCallbackDraw) {
        var nBtnPrevious = document.createElement('button');
        var nBtnNext = document.createElement('button');
        var nInput = document.createElement('select');
        var nPage = document.createElement('span');
        var nOf = document.createElement('span');
        nBtnPrevious.className = "paginate_button previous";
        nBtnPrevious.textContent = "Previous";
        nBtnNext.className = "paginate_button next";
        nBtnNext.textContent = "Next";
        nOf.className = "paginate_of";
        nPage.className = "paginate_page";
        if (oSettings.sTableId !== '') {
            nPaging.setAttribute('id', oSettings.sTableId + '_paginate');
        }
        nInput.style.display = "inline";
        nPage.innerHTML = "Page ";
        nPaging.appendChild(nBtnPrevious);
        nPaging.appendChild(nBtnNext);
        nPaging.appendChild(nPage);
        nPaging.appendChild(nInput);
        nPaging.appendChild(nOf);
        $(nBtnPrevious).click(function () {
            if( $(this).hasClass("disabled") )
                return;
            oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, "previous");
            fnCallbackDraw(oSettings);
        }).bind('selectstart', function () { return false; });
        $(nBtnNext).click(function () {
            if( $(this).hasClass("disabled") )
                return;
            oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, "next");
            fnCallbackDraw(oSettings);
        }).bind('selectstart', function () { return false; });
        $(nInput).change(function (e) {
            window.scroll(0,0);
            if (this.value === "" || this.value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
                return;
            }
            var iNewStart = oSettings._iDisplayLength * (this.value - 1);
            if (iNewStart > oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()) {
                oSettings._iDisplayStart = (Math.ceil((oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() - 1) / oSettings._iDisplayLength) - 1) * oSettings._iDisplayLength;
                fnCallbackDraw(oSettings);
                return;
            }
            oSettings._iDisplayStart = iNewStart;
            fnCallbackDraw(oSettings);
        });
        $('span', nPaging).bind('mousedown', function () {
            return false;
        });
        $('span', nPaging).bind('selectstart', function () {
            return false;
        });
    },
    "fnUpdate": function (oSettings, fnCallbackDraw) {
        if (!oSettings.aanFeatures.p) {
            return;
        }
        var iPages = Math.ceil((oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()) / oSettings._iDisplayLength);
        var iCurrentPage = Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength) + 1;
        var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
        for (var i = 0, iLen = an.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            var spans = an[i].getElementsByTagName('span');
            var inputs = an[i].getElementsByTagName('select');
            var elSel = inputs[0];
            if(elSel.options.length != iPages) {
                elSel.options.length = 0;
                for (var j = 0; j < iPages; j++) {
                    var oOption = document.createElement('option');
                    oOption.text = j + 1;
                    oOption.value = j + 1;
                    try {
                        elSel.add(oOption, null);
                    } catch (ex) {
                        elSel.add(oOption);
                    }
                }
                spans[1].innerHTML = "&nbsp;of&nbsp;" + iPages;
            }
          elSel.value = iCurrentPage;
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "pagingType": "listboxWithButtons"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
         <td>System Architect</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2011/04/25</td>
         <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Garrett Winters</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>63</td>
         <td>2011/07/25</td>
         <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Ashton Cox</td>
         <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>66</td>
         <td>2009/01/12</td>
         <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
         <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2012/03/29</td>
         <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Airi Satou</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>33</td>
         <td>2008/11/28</td>
         <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2012/12/02</td>
         <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>59</td>
         <td>2012/08/06</td>
         <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>55</td>
         <td>2010/10/14</td>
         <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
         <td>Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>39</td>
         <td>2009/09/15</td>
         <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Sonya Frost</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>2008/12/13</td>
         <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jena Gaines</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2008/12/19</td>
         <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
         <td>Support Lead</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2013/03/03</td>
         <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Charde Marshall</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>36</td>
         <td>2008/10/16</td>
         <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
         <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>43</td>
         <td>2012/12/18</td>
         <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>19</td>
         <td>2010/03/17</td>
         <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Michael Silva</td>
         <td>Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>66</td>
         <td>2012/11/27</td>
         <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Paul Byrd</td>
         <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2010/06/09</td>
         <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Gloria Little</td>
         <td>Systems Administrator</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>59</td>
         <td>2009/04/10</td>
         <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Bradley Greer</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>41</td>
         <td>2012/10/13</td>
         <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Dai Rios</td>
         <td>Personnel Lead</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>35</td>
         <td>2012/09/26</td>
         <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
         <td>Development Lead</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2011/09/03</td>
         <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Yuri Berry</td>
         <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>40</td>
         <td>2009/06/25</td>
         <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Caesar Vance</td>
         <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>2011/12/12</td>
         <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Doris Wilder</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>Sidney</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>2010/09/20</td>
         <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
         <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/10/09</td>
         <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>42</td>
         <td>2010/12/22</td>
         <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>28</td>
         <td>2010/11/14</td>
         <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>28</td>
         <td>2011/06/07</td>
         <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Fiona Green</td>
         <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>48</td>
         <td>2010/03/11</td>
         <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Shou Itou</td>
         <td>Regional Marketing</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>20</td>
         <td>2011/08/14</td>
         <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Michelle House</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>Sidney</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2011/06/02</td>
         <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Suki Burks</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>53</td>
         <td>2009/10/22</td>
         <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
         <td>Technical Author</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>27</td>
         <td>2011/05/07</td>
         <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
         <td>Team Leader</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2008/10/26</td>
         <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Martena Mccray</td>
         <td>Post-Sales support</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>46</td>
         <td>2011/03/09</td>
         <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Unity Butler</td>
         <td>Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/12/09</td>
         <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>51</td>
         <td>2008/12/16</td>
         <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
         <td>Secretary</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>41</td>
         <td>2010/02/12</td>
         <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
         <td>Financial Controller</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>62</td>
         <td>2009/02/14</td>
         <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2008/12/11</td>
         <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
         <td>Director</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>65</td>
         <td>2008/09/26</td>
         <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Olivia Liang</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2011/02/03</td>
         <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Bruno Nash</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>38</td>
         <td>2011/05/03</td>
         <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2009/08/19</td>
         <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Thor Walton</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2013/08/11</td>
         <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Finn Camacho</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/07/07</td>
         <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
         <td>Data Coordinator</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2012/04/09</td>
         <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>63</td>
         <td>2010/01/04</td>
         <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>56</td>
         <td>2012/06/01</td>
         <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
         <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>43</td>
         <td>2013/02/01</td>
         <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cara Stevens</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>46</td>
         <td>2011/12/06</td>
         <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Hermione Butler</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2011/03/21</td>
         <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Lael Greer</td>
         <td>Systems Administrator</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>2009/02/27</td>
         <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2010/07/14</td>
         <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Shad Decker</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>51</td>
         <td>2008/11/13</td>
         <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Michael Bruce</td>
         <td>Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>29</td>
         <td>2011/06/27</td>
         <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Donna Snider</td>
         <td>Customer Support</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>27</td>
         <td>2011/01/25</td>
         <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```